# Android OpenCV Mat file changes in a loop, how to refresh its Bitmap ImageView?

Tags: android, opencv, imageview

I'm updating the **Mat sum** values in a loop, which is in **OnCreate()**. And I want to see these changes in an **ImageView**, which is inside this loop but it refreshes only after completion of the loop... Invalidate and all other functions give no effect...

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  for (){
        ...
        Utils.matToBitmap(sum, slice_bitmap);
        ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.Pic);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(slice_bitmap);
  }
}
```

Comment: You need to call [`cv::waitKey(10 /*or whatever*/)`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.14/d7/dfc/group__highgui.html#ga5628525ad33f52eab17feebcfba38bd7) to give the GUI a chance to refresh.

Comment: Please give some more information, like more code.

Comment: Just citing from the stackoverflow: "It looks like OpenCV only has support for key events on desktop platforms, not mobile ones. The same is probably true of all the other "High-level GUI" functions." Though the logic of your answer is clear to me too, thank you...

Comment: Marcel Hofgesang / I will, I just thought that the short description is enough for those who came across this problem. It is about moving the scientific computations and simulations to mobile platforms...

Comment: tried this though             long l =10 ;
            try {
                wait(l);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }, so far with no success..))

Answer (score 0):

According to the android life cycle, The **visible** lifetime of an activity happens between a call to **onStart()** until a corresponding call to **onStop()**. Please take a look at this link:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity

The simplest way is to create a thread to show your pictures.

```
    // We usually have only one object for one Activity class. 
    //So we store the activity pointer in static variable then we can use it in anywhere.
    private static YourActivity mThisActivity = null;
    public static YourActivity getActivity() {return mThisActivity;};

    private ImageView mImageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ....
        mImageView = findViewById(R.id.Pic);
        mThisActivity = this;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        (new Thread(() -> {
            for (){
                ...
                Utils.matToBitmap(sum, slice_bitmap);
                YourActivity.getActivity().setImageView(slice_bitmap);
            }
        }).start();
    }

    // Every changing in UI must be run in UI Thread.
    // But don't include your matToBitmap() in the UI thread.
    // It will reduce the performance significantly.
    public void setImageView(Bitmap bitmap)
    {
        this.runOnUiThread(()->{
            mImageView.setImageBitmap(slice_bitmap);
        });
    }
```

Comment: JOE Thanks for the input: 1) I do need to pay a closer attention to placing the code in a proper app's lifecycle stage and use separate threads. 2) I did that you recommended and the most harmless problem is that if you place the loop (with rather intense scientific calculations using OpenCV on Android) into onStart the app keeps recalculating the loop again and again though it should do it only once,... but it is fixable...:). 3) It did not refresh the view...but only crushing everting with the first step of loop... trying to fix it now..

Answer (score 0):

Yeah! I did it! The correct answer is that the scientific calculations with the consecutive bitmap data recalculation should be moved to a separate thread in background, see [Android fundamentals 07.1:AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/codelabs/android-training-create-asynctask?index=..%2F..%2Fandroid-training#0), because "This type of intensive work can block the UI thread so that the app doesn't respond to user input or draw on the screen"

```
protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
...
My calculations to construct new bitmap
...
publishProgress(bitmapArray[0]);
}
```

and then you can update the **ImageView** through using something like

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(Bitmap... slice_bitmap0) {
mImageView.get().setImageBitmap(slice_bitmap0[0]);
}
```

which is run on UI thread and makes the UI's **ImageView** change the picture along the progress of your calculations. Here and there, I've used my code's variables and values specific names. So, it is all about not blocking the UI thread by anything but displaying the images and responding to the pushes of the buttons.

But this type of asynchronous calculations are depreciated started from API 30 :)